# Why is Convert.ToDateTime() not working in this example?

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use both System.DateTime.Now.ToString() and Convert.ToDateTime and was running into some strange behavior. I have narrowed down the problem to the Convert.ToDateTime. For some reason a DateTime type set with System.DateTime.Now is not the same as one that has been converted from a string. However when you output either of them they appear to be the same.

(I have tried using Trim(), TrimStart(), and TrimEnd() to no avail.)

This is the output in console after running this in unity:
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWsmB.jpg**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class DateTimeTest : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        //Save current time as a DateTime type
        DateTime saveTime = System.DateTime.Now;
        //Save above DateTime as a string
        string store = saveTime.ToString();
        //Convert it back to a DateTime type
        DateTime convertedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(store);

        //Output both DateTimes
        Debug.Log(saveTime + "\n" + convertedTime);

        //Output whether or not they match.
        if (saveTime == convertedTime)
            Debug.Log("Match: Yes");
        else
            Debug.Log("Match: No");

        //Output both DateTimes converted to binary.
        Debug.Log(saveTime.ToBinary() + "\n" + (convertedTime.ToBinary()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is fabricated, and hasn't any applicable reason. Why do you want such manipulations with `DatTime`? What is your primary goal?

Comment: Saving DateTime's in a file for later use. As I said, I narrowed it down to isolate the problem at it's source so it would be easier to understand and solve quickly, so I can see how you think it isn't applicable.

Comment: In that case you should use serialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You lose a lot when you convert a `DateTime` to a string via `DateTime.ToString()`.

Even if you include the milliseconds like this:

```
DateTime convertedTime =
    new DateTime(
        saveTime.Year,
        saveTime.Month,
        saveTime.Day,
        saveTime.Hour,
        saveTime.Minute,
        saveTime.Second,
        saveTime.Millisecond);
```

you would still get a different `DateTime` that is not equal to the original one.

The reason for this is that internally a `DateTime` stores a number of ticks (since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001). Each tick represents one ten-millionth of a second. You need to get the same number of Ticks for the two `DateTime` objects to be equal.

So, to get an equal `DateTime`, you need to do this:

```
DateTime convertedTime = new DateTime(saveTime.Ticks);
```

Or if you want to convert it to a string (to store it), you can store the ticks as a string like this:

```
string store = saveTime.Ticks.ToString();

DateTime convertedTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(store));
```

Answer (score 3):

The result of `DateTime.ToString()` does not include milliseconds. When you convert it back to `DateTime`, you basically truncate the milliseconds, so it returns a different value.

For example

```
var dateWithMilliseconds = new DateTime(2016, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 100);  
int beforeConversion = dateWithMilliseconds.Millisecond;  // 100

var dateAsString = dateWithMilliseconds.ToString();       // 04-01-16 1:00:00 AM (or similar, depends on culture)
var dateFromString = Convert.ToDateTime(dateAsString);
int afterConversion = dateFromString.Millisecond;         // 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way for me to concatenate the milliseconds back on before or after I convert the String back to a DateTime?

Comment: @Wafer It won't be enough. Check Yacoub Massad's answer - you need the same `Ticks` for 2 `DateTime`s to be equal. I don't think you can convert to a human-readable string and back without losing precision (unless of course you convert the `Ticks` directly).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are losing your time zone during the `ToString()` method. So the re-converted `DateTime` ends up in a different time zone.

Check also the `DateTime.Kind` property.